# Performance issue with matrix-matrix multiplication involving MaxRowsAtCompileTime / MaxColsAtCompileTime

Tags: gcc, matrix, eigen, eigen3

In the quest for optimal matrix-matrix multiplication using eigen3 (and hopefully profiting from SIMD support) I wrote the following test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <ctime>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

const int test_size= 13;
const int test_size_16b= test_size+1;

typedef Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic, ColMajor, test_size_16b,     test_size_16b> TestMatrix_dyn16b_t;
typedef Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic> TestMatrix_dynalloc_t;
typedef Matrix<double, test_size, test_size> TestMatrix_t;
typedef Matrix<double, test_size_16b, test_size_16b> TestMatrix_fix16b_t;

template<typename TestMatrix_t> EIGEN_DONT_INLINE void test(const char * msg, int m_size= test_size, int n= 10000) {
    double s= 0.0;
    clock_t elapsed= 0;
    TestMatrix_t m3;
    for(int i= 0; i<n; i++) {
        TestMatrix_t m1 = TestMatrix_t::Random(m_size, m_size);
        TestMatrix_t m2= TestMatrix_t::Random(m_size, m_size);

        clock_t begin = clock();
        m3.noalias()= m1*m2;
        clock_t end = clock();
        elapsed+= end - begin;

        // make sure m3 is not optimized away
        s+= m3(1, 1);
    }

    double elapsed_secs = double(elapsed) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << "Elapsed time " << msg << ": " << elapsed_secs << " size " << m3.cols() << ", " << m3.rows() << endl;
}

int main() {
#ifdef  EIGEN_VECTORIZE
    cout << "EIGEN_VECTORIZE on " << endl;
#endif

    test<TestMatrix_t>         ("normal   ");
    test<TestMatrix_dyn16b_t>  ("dyn 16b  ");
    test<TestMatrix_dynalloc_t>("dyn alloc");
    test<TestMatrix_fix16b_t>  ("fix 16b  ", test_size_16b);
}
```

compiled with `g++ -msse3 -O2 -DEIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE test.cpp` and ran it on an Athlon II X2 255. The result rather surprised me:

```
EIGEN_VECTORIZE on 
Elapsed time normal   : 0.019193 size 13, 13
Elapsed time dyn 16b  : 0.025226 size 13, 13
Elapsed time dyn alloc: 0.018648 size 13, 13
Elapsed time fix 16b  : 0.018221 size 14, 14
```

Similar results are attained with other odd numbers for `test_size`. What confuses me is this:

- From reading [Eigen Vectorization FAQ](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ#Vectorization) I would have thought that a 13x13 matrix has no multiple of 16 bytes size and thus will not profit from SIMD optimization. I expected the computation time to be much worse but it isn't.
- From reading about [Optional template parameters](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html) I would have thought that dynamic matrices with fixed upper bound known at compile time would behave much like dynamically allocated matrices an thus would have a similar computation speed. But they don't. That's actually what surprises me the most and what triggered my initial quest: I wanted to know if it is better to use a dynamic matrix with fixed upper bound that is a multiple of 16 bytes than a fixed size matrix whos size is not a multiple of 16 bytes.
- Finally interesting but not so much surprising: a matrix whos fixed size is a multiple of 16 is no slower that that of a matrix whos col and row length is one less. SIMD just does the extra col and row for free.
- Not my original question but also interesting: when the test is compiled without SSE2 support and thus without vectorization the relative computation times are roughly proportional. The dynamically sized fixed memory matrix is again slowest.

To put my question short: why is `Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic, ColMajor, test_size_16b, test_size_16b>` so much slower? Can you confirm my observations and maybe even explain them?

Answer (score 1):

The FAQ was obsolete. Since Eigen version 3.3, unaligned vectors and matrices are vectorized.

Then regarding why `Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic, ColMajor, test_size_16b, test_size_16b>` was slower, that was just an issue in the compile-time selection of the preferred matrix product implementation. The fix will be part of Eigen 3.3.1.